# The array returned by a function changed size between calls

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, scipy

I'm trying to solve for an array of values as explained in the following code. But I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-842-cf2c76a38adb>", line 25, in <module>
    y1[i] = fsolve(VLE_2,guess,args=(x1[i],T[i]))

  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scipy/optimize/minpack.py", line 148, in fsolve
    res = _root_hybr(func, x0, args, jac=fprime, **options)

  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scipy/optimize/minpack.py", line 227, in _root_hybr
    ml, mu, epsfcn, factor, diag)

ValueError: The array returned by a function changed size between calls
```

It's not shown in the code but T is a 500 elements array previously solved for.

```
P = 5000

x1 = np.linspace(0.1,1,500)
x2 = 1-x1

def VLE_2(y1,x1,T):
    y2=1-y1
    tau12 = a12+b12/T
    tau21 = a21+b21/T
    G12 = np.exp(-0.4*tau12)
    G21 = np.exp(-0.4*tau21)
    gamma_1 = np.exp((x2**2)*((tau21*G21**2)/(x1+x2*G21)**2+(tau12*G12)/(x2+x1*G12)**2))
    gamma_2 = np.exp((x1**2)*((tau12*G12**2)/(x2+x1*G12)**2+(tau21*G21)/(x1+x2*G21)**2))
    Psat1 = np.exp((106.1)-7614.8/T-12.686*np.log(T)+1.0733e-5*T**2)
    Psat2 = np.exp((84.912)-6722.2/T-9.5157*np.log(T)+7.2244e-6*T**2)
    #sol = np.zeros(2)
    return y1*P - x1*gamma_1*Psat1


y1 = np.ones(500)
guess = 0.9

for i in range(0,500):
    y1[i] = fsolve(VLE_2,guess,args=(x1[i],T[i]))
```

Comment: Im using Python 3 btw.

Comment: Please add the full error traceback to your question.

Comment: Edit your question and add it there as code-formatted text!

Comment: @KlausD. Thanks for the feedback!

Comment: Is it intended that your function refers to the `x2` variable defined outside of it, but doesn't use the `y2` variable you define inside? I'm wondering if the references to the former should be to the latter.

Comment: @Blckknght yes. I'm not using y2. I'm referring to x2 outside the function.

Comment: Since we can't copy-n-paste and run your code, you'll have to provide the debugging information.  Which `i` is causing the problem, what's the corresponding `x1[i]` etc.  Sounds like `VLE_2` is giving different size outputs depending on `guess` (`y1`) values.

Comment: Have to agree with @hpaulj... but have you tried simply `y1 = fsolve(VLE_2,guess,args=(x1,T)) `

Comment: @EmilVatai I have. I get the same error.

Comment: @hpaulj I don't know which i is causing the problem. I have an array of T which I can plot against x1 without a problem. I expect {VLE_2} to give me an array of y for every T and x value. I have tried an array of guess values but I get a broadcast error.

Comment: Let's get more basic, does this work? `fsolve(VLE_2,guess,args=(x1[0],T[0]))`.  Does `VLE_2(guess, x1[0], T[0])` work?

Comment: From the `fsolve` docs: `func: A function that takes at least one (possibly vector) argument, and returns a value of the same length`.  I take that to mean that if you provide a scalar `guess`, the `VLE_2` should return a scalar.

Comment: Let's ask another question - did you write this function and supporting code, or are you working with something  written by someone else, and which you don't thoroughly understand?  Have you coded and tested simpler `fsolve` cases?

Comment: @hpaulj. No, I get the same error. I tried x1[0] , T[0] and different guess values.

Comment: @hpaulj. Yeah I wrote the original code. Is there a way I can attach it to the original post?

Comment: @hpaulj. Sorry I'll be more specific `fsolve(VLE_2,guess,args=(x1[0],T[0]))` does not work.  `VLE_2(guess, x1[0], T[0])` YEs. this works.

Comment: I solved it. Thanks everyone for the input. I have to make x2 part of the function... 'VLE_2(y1,x1,x2,T)' otherwise its solving for one value of y per each x1,T but multiple x2 which would return an array of a different size than needed.